# GPIO.BOTH detects only falling edge

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have this Python 3 code running on a Raspberry Pi 4:

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from datetime import datetime

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

def change(channel):
    print("%s ch%s is %s" % (datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"), channel, GPIO.input(channel)))

GPIO.add_event_detect(27, GPIO.BOTH, callback=change)

time.sleep(100)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

I get this output:

```
14:42:25.706569 ch27 is 0
14:42:25.739840 ch27 is 0
14:42:25.789788 ch27 is 0
14:42:25.806397 ch27 is 0
14:42:25.824156 ch27 is 0
```

Since I'm using `GPIO.BOTH`, how is it possible that I detect only the falling edge, but not the rising edge?

Comment: What is generating the changes on the GPIO pin? Is it possible that it's changing fast enough that even though the function is triggered on the rising edge, the value has returned to `0` by the time you read it?

Comment: It's a machine that prints packaging.  But it should only change from 1 back to 0 after about 100ms.  It works as a standard "button" press.  And this button press should happen no more often than once every few seconds.  Unfortunately This Pi is several hundred miles away and I only have access to it over SSH.  I didn't add a hardware pulldown resistor before sending out the Pi, just the one I have in software.

Comment: In my code above, I changed `GPIO.BOTH` to `GPIO.RISING` and the callback was still called many times.  Your theory about a brief blip seems to have merit.  Perhaps as I've heard others say, the Pi's built in pulldown resistor is not strong enough to prevent this noise?  If that's the case, is there a way to fix this remotely via software?

Comment: @EricP It is not possible to change or add a pull up/down resistor remotely via SSH.

Comment: You can add a bouncetime to the add_event_detect to reduce the number of times the callback is called. eg. `GPIO.add_event_detect(27, GPIO.BOTH, callback=change, bouncetime=200)`. This arcticle talks about detecting inputs and reducing button bounce in hardware and software: [raspberry-gpio-inputs](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/)